# Updating opportunity with APEX code

Tags: apex, insert

I want to add products to a specific opportunity via APEX code. Not sure how I would be able to do that. I know how to create an opportunity and `insert` it into the environment but wanted to make it more specific so I can insert more child objects

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Salesforce [Product and Scehdule Objects Data Model](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_products.htm).

You will want to insert a collection of [OpportunityLineItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitem.htm) objects that are linked to the parent Opportunity via the `OpportunityId` field.

The OpportunityLineItem records should also use the same Pricebook2Id as the parent Opportunity and have a link to PricebookEntry records that correspond to the Porduct2 you want to link to.

You might find it easier to setup one or two sample Opportunity Product records via the UI and then examine them via SOQL to see what needs to be done.

Comment: and, if using multi-currency, the currency of the PBE / OLI must match the currency of the Opportunity